# QT: Private member instead of inheritance? What is the reason? Is this a specific concept?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, private-members

Some time ago I programmed a GUI with QT Designer / QT Creator. 
For this question I will first state a schematic of how the general process of creating a GUI with the mentioned IDE works:

1. Creating the design with the QT Designer -> Get .ui files
2. The .ui files are translated into header files and you especially get something like "UIbasisclass.h" (with class `UIbasisclass`) .
3. You create something like an "UIsubclass.h" (with class `UIsubclass`) yourself making one private member `UIbasisclass ui`.

Code within class `UIsubclass`:

```
...
        private:

       Ui::UIbasisclass ui;
...
```

Finally you will create an object of `UIsubclass` in the main method -> Code:

```
...
    UIsubclass *MyGUI = new UIsubclass();
...
```

where the constructor of UIsubclass consists among other code of:

```
...
    ui.setupUi(this); 
...
```

In short: We have a `UIsubclass` that is mostly responsible for applicational methods, but also has a private member of `UIbasisclass` named `ui` that consists mostly of design code. 
When we create an object of `UIsubclass` its private member `UIbasisclass ui` is initialized within the constructor of `UIsubclass` with the object of `UIsubclass` itself (?). [see: this pointer]

My questions are now:

1. Why isn't there used inheritance in the way that `UIsubclass` inherits from `UIbasisclass`? Instead one object of `UIbasisclass` becomes member of `UIsubclass`.
2. Is this some specific advantageous concept (if yes which advantages has it or how is it named?) or is it "just" a necessity of the QT code structure?

Let me know if I have to specify my questions or if there are any questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with private inheritance, it is even documented in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#the-multiple-inheritance-approach).

The use of a private member for ui is the default because of the templates used by Qt Creator, Qt itself does not care.

Comment: You're right. I should have checked the QT documentation first, didn't think about that possibility. There are a lot of informations regarding my questions. I' ll just check the informations and later mark your answer as solution

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't there used inheritance in the way that `UIsubclass` inherits from `UIbasisclass`?

You're asking us about why you didn't do it in your own code? Just do it. It's up to you. It truly is **your** code. **You** are responsible for its design. If you're using a template, it's there to help you get started, but not to design your software for you. The responsibility is yours, and yours only.

> it "just" a necessity of the QT code structure?

There is no such necessity. The `Ui` class is a POD class with a bunch of pointers and one method. Nothing much to it. If you want to privately inherit from it: go right ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Because with a private member you can forward declare the generated class:

```
namespace Ui {
    class MyForm;
}

class Foo {
private:
    Ui::MyForm *ui;    
};
```

and on the .cpp file you insert the include.

this way all of the possible includes of this file will not have to preprocess that file again.

Comment: These days it doesn't matter much for small projects, and for big projects you need precompiled headers or unity builds or PIMPLs to retain sane design that doesn't pessimize runtime performance just to get a slightly faster build time. You must first have compile time measurements that show benefit to this, and only then carefully choose how to speed up the debug build since presumably that's what you're concerned about.

Comment: It's not, because you will presumably have many other members that are separate from the `ui` member. PIMPL means that **everything** private is hidden, not only one thing. It'd only be a PIMPL if you were to put all other members into `Ui::MyForm` as well. I'm not saying that that's necessarily a bad idea: your PIMPL class certainly can derive from `Ui::MyForm` if you wish. Or it can have `Ui::MyForm` by value as a member.